# How to make a Boot disk for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I had a computer left to me but it's password protected. What can I do to remove the password?
It has windows 7 on it and it has a dvd drive.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the [NT Offline Password Editor](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/bootdisk.html) to change or blank the current password so you can get in. Here are some instructions: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/ss/ontpre-screenshot-guide.htm .

My recommendation is that you blank the password for now, and then boot to windows, login, and set a password of your choosing via windows.

You don't really need to create a boot disk to do this, but let us know if I am misunderstanding your issue.